# PHP CLI not respecting memory limit in php.ini

Tags: memory, php, php-cli, php.ini

I am using drush, which is a command-line php app to manage a drupal website. I am running a command to import a lot of data, which is causing me to hit php's memory limit.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted ...
```

Which is 512MB if I'm doing the math correctly (536870912 / 1024 / 1024 = 512). I've changed the directive in the php.ini that drush uses:

```
$> drush status
  ...
  PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini 
$> grep memory /etc/php5/cli/php.ini 
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 1024M
```

But I'm still hitting the 512 MB limit! I am running in a virtual machine, whose memory settings I changed from 512 to 1025 MB of RAM to allow drush to run.

```
$> free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1010        578        431          0         14        392
-/+ buffers/cache:        172        837
Swap:          382          0        382
```

So it says it has some 431 MB free, now that I've bumped the vm up to 1024. I guess half the memory is being used to run the GUI, but I don't understand how the GUI was running okay when the vm had 512 MB of ram.

Why is the PHP cli still hitting a 512 MB memory limit? If it was hitting a system memory limit, shouldn't it die around 431MB, which is what the `free` command says is available?

Comment: You're confusing virtual memory limits with physical memory limits. The PHP memory limit is a virtual memory limit. The output of `free` is all physical memory. Also, you are wrong about half the memory being used to run the GUI. The memory is used largely for buffers and cache. The system simply hasn't bothered to make it free because it already has sufficient free memory, so it would be wasted effort.

Comment: Most likely, you have more than one `php.ini` file (check something like `/etc/php5/cli`) and are editing the wrong one or you have a `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` setting in a `settings.php` file or the like that is getting included.

Comment: @David - I had an extra ini_set() in the coedbase hanging around from troubleshooting code. IF you post that answer I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, you have more than one php.ini file (check something like `/etc/php5/cli`) and are editing the wrong one or you have a `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` setting in a `settings.php` file or the like that is getting included.

Answer (score 3):

For other people who google this question like me - run this command:

```
php --ini
```

To see which configuration php-cli is using.
You will see something like this:

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

Or like this:

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/php-7.0.26/etc/php.ini
```

Maybe you are trying to change configuration in a wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac for instance

`/etc/php5/cli` is for command line, so you need to change `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini`

That should work!